# In an infinite consecutive set of only all the prime numbers, should we expect consecutive twin prime numbers to exist infinitely?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes

I am aware that in an infinite consecutive set of all positive integers, in theory there should be infinite twin prime numbers, but let's imagine an infinite set of only all the prime numbers.

Here are some examples of consecutive twin prime numbers in a consecutive set of only all prime numbers:

$(101, 103) (107, 109)$

$(137, 139) (149, 151)$

$(179, 181) (191, 193) (197, 199)$

$(419, 421) (431, 433)$

$(809, 811) (821, 823)$

$(1019, 1021) (1031, 1033)$

...

$(4217, 4219)  (4229, 4231)  (4241, 4243)$

...

I know that there are no proofs yet, but theoretically:

A)Is there a limit to how many consecutive twin primes can occur in such a set?

B)Are we expecting to have these consecutive twin primes occur infinitely in such a set?

Comment: +1 : interesting query.

Comment: First a remark : At the beginning you mention the argument that infinite many twin primes can be expected since there are infinite many positive integers. In general, such a conclusion is utterly wrong , witness the idoneal numbers which form a finite set , a fact far from being obvious.

Comment: But now to the question : $(1)$ If we just demand a given number of twin primes no matter where in the sequence they occur, the existence follows from the twin prime conjecture. $(2)$ But you probably mean something like differences $2,14,2,12,2,8,2,16$ and this should be feasible with a suitable admissable tuple.

Comment: If we can show that there are tuples with arbitary many differences $2$ seperated by only one other difference (which I think can be done, but I have no proof yet), then we can expect infinite many tuples doing the job and hence no limit in the number of twins.

Comment: Relevant: http://oeis.org/A087641.

Comment: @nickgard very much relevant indeed, and now I know that the term to search is “twin prime clusters”

Comment: @Peter I have updated the question per your first remark to include “all positive integers”.

Comment: I would think there is no infinite sequence - that would mean that from some point all primes are twin primes. For arbitrarily long sequences - that’s probably part of the (Hardy-Littlewood?) conjecture that any pattern of prime numbers that isn’t obviously impossible will occur infinitely often.

Comment: No infinite sequence exists. By Dirichlet's theorem, there are infinite primes of the form $p=15n+7$, but then $5|p-2$ and $3|p+2$.